# Internet connection is sluggish

Tags: 11.10, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a desktop computer with an Ethernet connection.

Pc specifications:
AMD Sempron 145 Sargas 2.8GHz Socket AM3 45W Single-Core Desktop Processor SDX145HBGMBOX,
2-2Gb of ram; 4Gb in total,
Biostar TA880GB+ Motherboard,
300Gb SATA-Hard Drive,
Os- Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

My computer's internet connection seems a bit sluggish, even though it is on an Ethernet connection. My friend's laptop (Windows Vista 32-bit) is on the same network but seems to run faster even though it is on a wire-less connection. I've complained to my internet carrier but have not found a solution to it yet. I've tried different browsers also, such as Chromium, Google Chrome, and Fire Fox. But no luck as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a couple of things.

First, Ubuntu might be trying to talk IPv6. Normally that's not an issue, but it can be if your network equipment is old, misconfigured, or just lower end. [A quick Google search reveals how to to do this](http://pario.no/2011/12/09/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-11-10/).

If IPv6 isn't the problem, you might try changing nameservers. Go to the application called Network Connections and edit your connection. From there, go to the IPv4 tab and choose "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only". Enter [Google's public and free nameservers](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/):

[image: Network Settings - DNS]

Answer (score 0):

What is your internet connection? If it's ADSL, you should probably reduce your MTU. See http://www.dslreports.com/faq/7801 and http://www.dslreports.com/faq/5793

The MTU is the Maximum Transmission Unit (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit))

If your MTU is too large, every TCP packet you send will be broken into TWO (or more) packets, and you'll experience slowth.